# Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.Expected server HTML to contain a matching <button> in <button>

Tags: next.js

"use client";
import { MenuIcon, Search, BellIcon, FacebookIcon, TwitterIcon, YoutubeIcon } from "lucide-react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Sheet, SheetContent, SheetFooter, SheetHeader, SheetTitle, SheetTrigger } from "@/components/ui/sheet";

const MegaNav = () => {

```
const date = new Date();
const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric'
};
const today = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('bn-BD', options).format(date);

return (
    <nav className="w-full h-28 border-b">
        <div className="container p-4 px-8 mx-auto flex justify-between">
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
                <div className="flex items-center">
                    <Sheet>
                        <SheetTrigger>
                            <Button variant="ghost" size="sm"><MenuIcon className="w-8 h-8" /></Button>
                        </SheetTrigger>
                        <SheetContent side={"left"}>
                            <SheetHeader className="py-6">
                                <SheetTitle>প্রথম আলো</SheetTitle>
                            </SheetHeader>
                            <div className="grid gap-4 py-4 font-semibold text-sm">
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">সর্বশেষ</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">বিশেষ সংবাদ</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">রাজনীতি</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">বাংলাদেশ</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">অপরাধ</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">বিশ্ব</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">বাণিজ্য</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">মতামত</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">খেলা</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">বিনোদন</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">চাকরি</Link>
                                <Link href="/" className="border-b pb-2">জীবনযাপন</Link>
                            </div>
                            <SheetFooter className="grid gap-4 my-4">
                                <span className="font-semibold text-sm">অনুসরণ করুন-</span>
                                <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                                    <Link href="/"><FacebookIcon /></Link>
                                    <Link href="/"><TwitterIcon /></Link>
                                    <Link href="/"><YoutubeIcon /></Link>
                                </div>
                            </SheetFooter>
                        </SheetContent>
                    </Sheet>

                    <Button variant="ghost" size="sm">
                        <Search className="w-5 h-5" />
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className="text-sm text-slate-500">
                    {today}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Image src="/images/prothom-alo.png" alt="Logo" width={270} height={150} />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-between">
                <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                    <Button variant="ghost" size="sm">
                        <BellIcon className="w-6 h-6" />
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="outline" size="sm">
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div className="text-black font-semibold text-sm flex gap-2 justify-end">
                    <Link href="/">English</Link>
                    <span className="text-slate-500">Edition</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
```

}

export default MegaNav;

whats going wrong? why show Hydration failed